# How to do fullscreen slanted line in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a slanted line that will extend to the whole page. But currently the line have tiny gap on the left and right margin.

Html :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">   
  <div class="row shine">
        <div class="col-lg-7 shine-content text-center">
            <h3>No.1 Bestseller</h3>
            <h1>Rouge Volupte Shine</h1>
            <p>Satin finish. Iconic lipstick. Highly pigmented. A wardrobe of iconic colors that symbolises audacious feminine strength.</p>
    </div>
      
        <div class="col-lg-5 shine-img d-flex justify-content-center px-5">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    
<div class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row rouge">
        <div class="col-lg-6 rouge-img d-flex justify-content-center px-5">
      
          
        <div class="col-lg-6 rouge-content text-center">
            <h1>Rouge Pur Couture</h1>
            <p>In just one stroke, luxurious and highly pigmented colour dresses the lips with a radiant satin finish. Rouge Pur Couture delivers the promise of edgy style and ultimate feminine strength. </p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
hr{
    margin:100px 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #777777;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
}
```

https://codepen.io/jl-joey/pen/OJXdGJP

Comment: Looks like the default body margin is taking effect. Reset it and use margins for elements other than the line.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is there is a margin of body which is setted by defauly browser.
Therefore here is the solution.
Set body margin be 0px, and scale a little bit of the line and then set the container-fluid overflow being hidden.

```css
hr{
    margin:100px 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #777777;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1.05);
    
}   
body{
  margin:0px;
}
.container-fluid{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">   
  <div class="row shine">
        <div class="col-lg-7 shine-content text-center">
            <h3>No.1 Bestseller</h3>
            <h1>Rouge Volupte Shine</h1>
            <p>Satin finish. Iconic lipstick. Highly pigmented. A wardrobe of iconic colors that symbolises audacious feminine strength.</p>
            
        
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-lg-5 shine-img d-flex justify-content-center px-5">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    
<div class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row rouge">
        <div class="col-lg-6 rouge-img d-flex justify-content-center px-5">
      
          
        <div class="col-lg-6 rouge-content text-center">
            <h1>Rouge Pur Couture</h1>
            <p>In just one stroke, luxurious and highly pigmented colour dresses the lips with a radiant satin finish. Rouge Pur Couture delivers the promise of edgy style and ultimate feminine strength. </p>
            
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet seems has padding, you need to stick the code to your codepen, and then you should see the final expected result.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file give margin:0 ; padding: 0 to your body tag like below:
**body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}**

and for your hr tag style include the margin 100px -5px}

hr {**margin: 100px -5px;** `rest your previous style`}

**Note:** you can change margin right and left value from  -5px as per your required size.